# Configuration error: found multiple declarations of @BootstrapWith for test class in Junit

Tags: mockito, junit5, spring-test

I want to create a Rest API test for endpoint:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/dashboard", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class DashboardController {

    private UserService userService;

    @GetMapping(value = "/users", produces =
            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<List<UserSummaryDTO>> getUserSummary(........)
    {
       .....
        return userService.getUserSummary(......);
    }
}
```

I tried this JUnit test:

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.containsString;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers.print;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.content;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@SpringBootTest(classes=DashboardController.class)
@WebMvcTest(DashboardController.class)
public class GenericTest {

    @MockBean
    private UserService service;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void dashboardDataTest() throws Exception
    {
        when(service.getUserSummary(any(), any())).thenReturn(Optional.of(List.of(UserSummaryDTO.builder().build())));
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/dashboard/users")).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().string(containsString("Hello, Mock")));
    }
}
```

But I get this exception:

```
Configuration error: found multiple declarations of @BootstrapWith for test class [org.GenericTest]: [@org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapWith(value=org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.class), @org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapWith(value=org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTestContextBootstrapper.class)]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Configuration error: found multiple declarations of @BootstrapWith for test class [org.GenericTest]: [@org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapWith(value=org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.class), @org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapWith(value=org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTestContextBootstrapper.class)]
```

Do you know how I can solve this issue?

Comment: You cannot have `@SpringBootTest` and `@WebMvcTest` at the same time. You must decide for one of the two annotations